# Typed Datasets or Entity Framework for an online game server?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, strongly-typed-dataset

My game is turnbased, but it does have some realtime elements like chat, so it needs to be speedy.  One server should ideally support a couple thousand online players.

I know Datasets tend to store large amounts of data in memory but I figured that's what I needed to avoid having to do db calls twice every milliscecond. I'm leaning away from Entity Framework because I don't seem to have as much control of whats happens under the hood, and it struck me as less efficient somehow.

Now I know neither of these (nor c# in general) are the most blazingly fast solution to ever exist in life but I do need a little convenience.

By the way I can't easily use .Net 4.0 because of some other iffy dependencies. Those could be fixed but to be honest I don't feel like investing the time in figuring it out. I rather just stick with 3.5 which my dependencies work well with.

Comment: Stay away from EF if performance is a concern.  Just use ADO.Net with your own SQL / stored procs.

Comment: Are you trying to use typed datasets as an in-memory cache to avoid going to the database all the time?

Comment: Yep @Tombala that's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: @dbaseman but if I was deadset on using either Entity Framework or Typed Datasets you'd side strongly with Datasets?

Comment: @user1379635 really depends.  How big are the datasets?  Are most of the DB interactions reads (which you could cache), or are there a lot of writes?  The question (IMHO) needs to be more specific / fleshed out to get a good answer.

Comment: @dbaseman right now I have it set up to do writes on an interval (every so and so seconds it updates the database with the new info). The records are probably going to be updated (in the memory cache) pretty often. Chat is going to be all reads (reading which users can hear the messages) but the other mechanics of the game (like turn-based combat) is probably going to be nearly equal reads and writes.

At max capacity the dataset will have 5 or 6 tables with a couple thousand records each (all logged in players). The in-memory tables are joins of db tables.

Comment: It sounds like your datasets will be growing in memory. At a few thousands or rows, it won't be a huge footprint but the problem will start when you're trying to commit changes. If the dataset has to settle thousands of rows, you might see a performance hit. But otherwise, I don't see you having much problem with data volumes and number of tables you're talking about. It's not the most efficient. But it will probably work. :)

Answer (score 3):

I have done a game with a database back-end.

Word to the wise: updating caches in a real-time game is difficult.  Your players will be interacting all the time.   You have to think about whether you want to keep all players on the same server - if so, caching is simple, but you will limit growth.  If not, think how you can keep people interacting on the same server.  A chat server, for example, would solve the chat issues.  However if you have geography, you might want to segment by world areas, if you don't, might want to keep groups of players, or if you have different game instances, you can segment by that.

Another issue is locking - your players might access the same data that another is updating.  You will almost certainly have to deal with transaction isolation levels - i. e. read uncommitted will help with locking.  For this, ADO offers more control.

However EF lets you write much cleaner update code,  and the performance will not be different if you are updating by ID.

You could go for a mix - read via ADO and write via EF.   You could even write a transactional db context that uses ADO underneath.  That way they look alike but do different things in the background.

Just my thoughts, I hope this helps you figure out your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is the chat you can choose different kind of solutions for it, using external cloud systems that provied messeging and breadcasting...

Check out this link : 
http://www.pubnub.com/solutions/how-pubnub-works

Hoped i helped at some way

Comment: That looks cool, but I rather not go too 3rd-party with this one.

Answer (score 0):

It does not sound like either solution is an ideal fit for your problem. Your question is therefore like asking whether to use a wet newspaper or an umbrella to drive a nail into the wall.. regardless of the answer, you probably should do neither.

EF comes with a lot of limitations and quirks, and does have some overhead. If you really want to stick to 3.5 (poor choice in my opinion, but hey), then I wouldn't recommend it - unless you are already comfortable with it, including how to troubleshoot any performance issues.

DataSets are just an abomination. It is my professional belief that they were invented in order for Microsoft to be able to pull of their 5-minute drag-and-drop coding demos for Visual Studio, in order to convince all the VB programmers to switch to .NET. They are exceptionally slow compared to just about everything (although since .NET 2.0 performance does at least scale linearly).

I am not sure exactly what product you should be using, but I know there are in-memory relational databases that allow you to store transaction logs and the occasional snapshot, in order to facilitate rollback in case your server dies (or IIS is restarted, etc.), which gives you performance at the cost of scalability (your entire database must fit in memory).

Another option is to use a NoSQL database (such as MongoDB), which scales really well across multiple servers, and lets you bundle all related data into a single document (so you don't have all the overhead of joining tables when querying for data).

Either one of these options are going to be a much better fit than any of the two original suggestions.